# Creating a function for a random number 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, function, matrix, random

So, I have this code which I need to turn into a function:

```
int main(void)  {
    int i=0,seed;
    printf("\n\nEnter seed integer value: ");               
    scanf("%d", &seed);                         
    printf("\nSeed value is:%d\n\n",seed);                  
    srand(seed);



    int a[5][5];                                
    int x,y;
    printf("Matrix A:\n");
    for(x=0;x<5;x++)    {                       
        for(y=0;y<5;y++)    {
            a[x][y] = rand() %51 + (-25);               
            printf("%d  ",a[x][y]); }           
        printf("\n");   }
    printf("\n\n");
```

So basically, it produces a 2D 5x5 array of random numbers. This works fine, however my next task is applying a function to this code, with the function name of:

```
void generate_matrices(int a[5][5])
```

I have tried multiple times, the closest I got to a successful code was:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void generate_matrices(int a[5][5]);

int main(void)  {
    int a, seed;
    printf("\n\nEnter seed integer value: ");               
    scanf("%d", &seed);
    srand(seed);
    printf("\nSeed value is:%d\n\n",seed);  

    generate_matrices(a);

    return 0;
}


void generate_matrices(int a[5][5]) {

    int y,z;
    printf("Matrix A:\n");
    for(y=0;y<5;y++)    {
        for(z=0;z<5;z++)    {
             a[y][z] = rand() %51 + (-25);  }   
    printf("%d  ",a[y][z]); }
    printf("\n");
    }
```

But this returns the error, "expected 'int(*)[5]' but arguement is of type 'int'.

All/any help is muchly appreciated. To be fair on my part, I have done 90% of the code. This is the only bit I need help with so that I can apply this to the rest of my code.

Cheers!

Comment: You can't send an array as a variable. You need to send a pointer that points to its first element + column size + row size. Or just don't send it ! Create it inside that function and process it there

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `a` as a single integer on this line `int a, seed;`

When you call the function with `generate_matrices(a);`  you are passing  a single integer instead of a pointer to an array.
Change your declaration line to `int a[5][5], seed;`

`generate_matrices(a);`  will pass a pointer to the first element in your 5 * 5 array, to the function.

You should really print the results in `main` and not in the function, then you will know that the array has been modified and is available for use in the body of your program.

You have used unconventional placement of braces '}' and this makes it harder to see what belongs in each part of your `for` loops.
You have the print statements in the wrong places - as a result only part of the matrix is printed.

This is what it should be (just the results - in main):

```
printf("Matrix\n ");
for (y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
    for (z = 0; z < 5; z++) {
         printf("%d\t  ", a[y][z]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

If you use `int a[5][5]` and call the function with `generate_matrices(a);`
a function `void generate_matrices(int a[5][5]) {...}` compiles without error

Comment: I see. Printing the output matrix needs to have another function however, the function void generate_matrices(int a[5][5]); is just to generate the matrix, then I need to use another function of void print_matrix(int a[5][5]);

So in my first set of coding I put up, i'm disregarding (for now) printing the matrix, I just want no errors to occur when I compile the code.

Comment: A function `void print_matrix(int a[5][5]){...}` can be called in the same way `print_matrix(a);` and place the print code in it. Also you need to pass the seed value to the generate_matrix function, and use it to generate the random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void modify(int b[5][5]);
int main()
{
    srand(4562);
    int i,j,arr[5][5];
    modify(arr);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(j=0;j<5;j++){
            printf("%d  ",arr[i][j]=rand() %51 + (-26)); }
    }
    return 0;
}

void modify(int b[5][5])
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++) {
            b[i][j]; }
    }
}
```

So this is the closest I have come to completing it. It produces the number of elements I want, also within the range I want. However its not producing the 5x5 grid I need. Where have I gone wrong?

EDIT: I'm not going for neatness at the moment, I just want to get the program working how I want it too and then i'll neaten it up.

EDIT 2: Never mind, realised what I didn't include. Its fine now. Thanks for the help.